# how to add column by using other column's conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'month':np.arange(1,8)})
```

So,I would like to add column by using 'month' columns

```
if 'month'=1,2,3   the elements = 'term1'
   'month'=4,5     the elements = 'term2' 
   'month'=6,7     the elements = 'term3'
```

I would like to get the result below

```
      month  term 
0       1    term1
1       2    term1
2       3    term1
3       4    term2
4       5    term2
5       6    term3
6       7    term3
```

How can I get this result?
maybe we could get this result easy and simple way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a declarative way through a dict, simple to read and easy to apply. You can generate your replace condition dictionary programmatically if the replacement conditions become large or depends on other inputs:

```
conditions = {1:'term1', 2:'term1', 3:'term1',
              4:'term2', 5:'term2',
              6:'term3', 7:'term3'}

df['term'] = df.replace(conditions)
df

      month  term 
0       1    term1
1       2    term1
2       3    term1
3       4    term2
4       5    term2
5       6    term3
6       7    term3
```

Comment: very simple! how can I add this column to df ?

Comment: as usual: `df['term'] = df.replace(conditions)`

Comment: thank you!  so, suppose,  month>7 =　term4  how can I describe?

Comment: add the terms 8 to 12 in the conditions dict

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.where` and `Series.isin()` method could be one of the options to do it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df["term"] = np.where(df.month.isin([1,2,3]), "term1", \
                      np.where(df.month.isin([4,5]), "term2", "term3"))

df
# month  term
#0    1 term1
#1    2 term1
#2    3 term1
#3    4 term2
#4    5 term2
#5    6 term3
#6    7 term3
```